# I'm trying to redirect a embedded item in sites.google.com but isn't working. Only makes website insecure. Tried everything I could in google sites

Tags: html, google-sites

I'm trying to redirect a embedded item in sites.google.com but isn't working. Only makes website insecure. Tried everything I could in google sites!
My Javacript isn't working it's on id="div2" and the script is under it.
My Website looks better on here https://sites.google.com/haledon.org/disstrack/home.

Here is My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#div1").click(function(){
            $("video").remove();
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
.mystyle {
    display: none;
}
.style2{
    display: block;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-right: ;
}
body{
background:
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<style>
html {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
 margin-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

a {
 text-decoration: inherit;
}

.myButton {
 color: #31A6FF !important;
 font-family: "proxima nova" !important;
 font-weight: 75 !important;
 font-size: 20px !important;
 text-align: center !important;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 0px;
 border: solid 1px #31A6FF !important;
 border-radius: 25px !important;

 padding: 10px 80px;

 -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
 transition-duration: 200ms;
}

.myButton:hover {
 background-color: #31A6FF !important;
 color: #fff !important;
}
</style>

<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.myButton{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 27%;
    width: 200px;
    transform: translate(-15%, -45%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-15%, -45%);
    background-color: ;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container .btn:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div2" class="mystyle">
  <img class="" src="http://people.bath.ac.uk/su9urb/img/youtubeerror.png" alt="Snow" title="Subscribe to PewDiePie" style="width:700px;height:400px;" >
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/PewDiePie" class="myButton"  target="_top" onmouseover="myLocation()">Subscribe to PewDiePie</a>
  <!--<button class="myButton btn">Button</button>-->
</div>
<script>
    function myLocation() {
        setTimeout("window.top.location.href = 'https://gaetanofederici.ga/home.html';",3800);
    }
</script>

<div id="div1" class="">
<video width="700px;" height="400px" id="myVideo" controls controlsList="nodownload" style="margin-left: -25%;" muted>
  <source src="https://zeweyezelo.000webhostapp.com/9year.mp4" type="video/ogg">
  <!--<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">-->
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</video>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("myVideo").onplay = function() {myFunction()};

    function myFunction() {
       var element = document.getElementById("myVideo");
       element.classList.add("mystyle");
       var img = document.getElementById("div2");
       img.classList.add("style2");
    }

</script>

<!--<button>Remove all p elements</button>-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well one reason your website is probably being shown as insecure is because this image `http://people.bath.ac.uk/su9urb/img/youtubeerror.png` is not being loaded from `https` which it should be.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest putting your scripts in a separate .js file and your styles in a .css file since it is hard to follow the code, also please remove anything commented out if not necessary.

Comment: And if you are trying to redirect the page using javascript to an external site I think that violates the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and the browser will not allow it because that is unsafe.

Comment: ok thank u I will try what u all said